# Ajax conection fails

Tags: ajax, laravel, phonegap

I made a mobile app using Phonegap. I use Ajax to get the data from the server. The server has a Laravel aplication that give the data in Json. This is the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".loader").show();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://miIp/public/menu',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
                    $("#conectionError").hide();

                    if(data == 1){
                        $('#liveStreaming').show();
                        $("#live_choose").show();
                        $(".btn_menu").hide();
                    }
                    if(data == 0){
                        $('#liveStreaming').hide();
                        $("#live_choose").hide();
                        $(".btn_menu").show();
                        $('#liveStreaming').hide();
                    }
                    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
                },
                error:function(){
                    $(".loader").hide();
                    var divHeight = $("#conectionError").height();
                    var imgHeight = $("#conectionErrorImg").height();
                    var imgMargin = (divHeight - imgHeight)/2;

                    $("#conectionErrorImg").css("margin-top", imgMargin);

                    $("#conectionError").show();
                },
                async: true
            });
        });
    });
```

I tested the app locally (I had the laravel aplication in Xampp) and works ok. I even compile the app with phonegap build, and I tested it in my phone, and works ok.

Today I uploaded the Laravel aplication to a cloud server on WIROO, but the mobile app doesn't get data. I put the links on chrome and I can see the data in Json, but ajax fails over and over again.

I supose tha may be is a permission issue (I am using Vesta Panel), but I don't understand anything of this.

¿Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you tell us about your cors setup and and how your csrf token is being put into js?

Comment: where is the method?

Comment: Check your url first